# invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type struct

Tags: c, struct, incomplete-type

this is a bit puzzling to me because it worked in the past.

I have a vector3 struct and a matrix4 struct which are defined like this

[image]

common_struct.h looks like this

```
struct {
    float m[16];
} mat4_scalar;

struct {
    float p[3];
} vector3_scalar;
```

then In my vector3_scalar.h I have functions like these:

```
#include "../../common/common_structs.h"

struct vector3_scalar* vec3_zero(void);
struct vector3_scalar* vec3_up(void);
struct vector3_scalar* vec3_right(void);
struct vector3_scalar* vec3_forward(void);
```

in my vector3_scalar.c I am trying to malloc a vector3_scalar like this:

```
#include "../headers/vector3_scalar.h"

struct vector3_scalar* v = (struct vector3_scalar*)malloc(sizeof(struct  vector3_scalar)); //<--- error occurs here
```

but I am getting invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type struct vector3_scalar

I've also tried including the common_structs.h directly in the .c file but that doesn't seem to help either.

What am I doing wrong in this situation?

Comment: No, it didn't ever work

Comment: thanks for the insightful comment @DavidHeffernan, that really helped me solve my problem.

Comment: Well it didn't ever work did it? In other words the question contains erroneous information.

Comment: actually it worked just fine, initially it was typedef struct { }vector3_scalar; I removed the typedef and didn't define the struct the proper way and so I was having issues. So yes in fact it did work.

Comment: No it did not. Different code might have worked. The code here never did.

Comment: I won't disavow you of your beliefs but I would ask you to kindly leave me and this discussion, a solution has been accepted. There's absolutely no reason for you to continue to respond, have a nice day.

Comment: I was just trying to explain to you that what changed was your code. It's not about belief. It's about fact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
struct {
    float p[3];
} vector3_scalar;
```

This declares a variable named `vector3_scalar` of type "unnamed struct". You want

```
struct vector3_scalar {
    float p[3];
};
```

Better yet

```
typedef struct {
    float p[3];
} vector3_scalar;
```

and then use just `vector3_scalar` (not `struct vector3_scalar`) everywhere.

Comment: thank you, I was doing the typedef struct .... in the beginning and that was working. I just forgot to properly setup my struct. I moved the typedefs to a header so that I can have different implementations of those, neon, simd, scalar so if you are using the code the api doesn't change but i can add improvements over time.